# Visual Studio Code - IntelliSense missing for static methods

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've installed Visual Studio Code 0.10.8 with ms-vscode.PowerShell-0.4.1 extension.

IntelliSense ([ctrl]+[space]) is working fine:

[image: intellisense]

... but not for static methods:

[image: intellisense]

There are no such problems in PowerShell ISE:

[image]

I really like the feel and speed of vscode, but I'm working with lots of .NET classes and won't switch from ISE without full IntelliSense support. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Seems you should ask the developer of that extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in official PowerShell support for Visual Studio Code.

You may have either found a bug, or a missing featuring of the PowerShell extension.

I'd recommend posting an issue on their GitHub repo: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell